# UIScrollView Starts at bottom on Landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uiscrollview

I am working on form with multiple `UITextfields` in to that.. and when I run this app in `Landscape` mode my `View` starts at bottom of the page not from the top  ..So I used UIScrollView I just dragged the `scrollView` on my View from XIB and Top of it I Put UITextfields..

In `portrait`, everything works fine as it is on single page. but in `landscape` view Starts at bottom of page.in Code I just added `setContentSize` and `setScrollEnabled`. what should I do to start from top in landscape mode

Comment: Looks like an issue with Autoresizing mask

Comment: go to xib file and set the scrollView .. Shows Vertical Scrollers..set unchecked

Comment: @RinjuJain not working with this